# html: have form adjust width to contents?

Tags: html, css

please have a look at this simple jsfiddle:

[--> JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Nimral/uv8yrrav/9/)

html:

```
<form>
  <p>
    <input id="I1" value="above left" size="40" />
    <input id="I2" value="above right" size="10" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input id="I3" value="below right" size="10" />
    <input id="I4" value="below left" size="20" />
  </p>
</form>
```

css:

```
form {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}

#I1,
#I2 {
  background-color: orange;
  float: left;
}

#I3,
#I4 {
  background-color: yellow;
  float: right;
}
```

what I want is the red border (= form width) auto-adjust to the width of the two top inputs (+ padding, of course).

I would then expect, that the second line inputs appear right-aligned below the first, so "above right" would be exactly above "below right", and "below left" beeing right left of it, like so:

```
11111111111111111111 2222222
             4444444 3333333
```

Can this be done without tables?

Thx, Armin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It most certainly can be done without tables :). You could set, for form:

```
form {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: ...;
}
```

This will prevent the form from expanding to the entire width of the screen. It will be as wide as the elements inside it, or, if you manually define its width, as wide as specified.

If you would like no elements to appear on either side of the form within the form's containing element, you can wrap it in a div or other block level element:

```
<div>
  <form>
    <!-- Rest of content -->
  </form>
</div>
```

In order to remove the spacing above and below each `p`, as per your comment, remove their margin-top and margin-bottom, as they have a margin by default:

```
p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks very much for this hint, now I got quite close to what I want, see JSFiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Nimral/uv8yrrav/23/). Like it is always in css, I get an unwanted side effect: tehr is a lot of whitespace inserted above the top row of elements. I think I can figure this out ...

Comment: Figured this out myself. Replaced the paragraphs with divs, and now everything looks fine. See: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Nimral/uv8yrrav/24/)

Answer (score 0):

I have update this answer. Probably this is what you need, but there are other options but I don't think is the scope of this question.

CSS Code:

```
form {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 400px; // limites de form size
}
#I1,
#I2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: orange;
}
#I3,
#I4 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
}
p {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  height: 2em; 
}
#I1,
#I4 {
   right: 25%;
}
#I2,
#I3 {
    right: 0;
}
```

See here the full code: https://jsfiddle.net/uv8yrrav/18/

hope this helps!

Comment: Hi,this comes close, but does not exactly what I wanted. If I make the explorer window wider than the width of the 2 top elements, they are torn apart from each other, I wanted them to stay together, and the form not increase its size instead. Second, the two bottom inputs are left-right justified, I wanted the two stay together as well, with the white space appearing to the left of "below left".

Comment: I clarified my original question to show what I need.

Comment: I have update the code to meet the requirements hope this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I've organized and cleaned-up your code. The way to make the div adjust to its content is by using `display: inline-block`. I've also fixed the padding issue so now the entire content is padded equally to 5px.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uv8yrrav/20/)

HTML:

```
<form>
  <p>
    <input id="I1" value="above left" size="40" />
    <input id="I2" value="above right" size="10" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input id="I3" value="below right" size="10" />
    <input id="I4" value="below left" size="20" />
  </p>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.border {
  border: 3px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#I1 {
  background-color: orange;
}

#I2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.top-block,
.bottom-block {
  width: 100%;
}
```